# Complete absortion of a photon by an atom (from the perspective of conservation laws)

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws, atoms

It is very simple to show that an isolated charged particle cannot completely absorb a photon, since that would contradict the conservation of linear momentum or energy: consider a system where the charged particle of mass $m$ is at rest and a photon impinging on it with energy $E_\gamma$, the conservation of linear momentum (assuming complete absorption) would lead to:
$$\frac{E_\gamma}{c} + 0 = 0 + p, \qquad (1)$$
Conservation of energy would entail that:
$$E_\gamma + mc^2 = \sqrt{p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}, \qquad (2)$$
Substituting $(1)$ in two, we arrive at an equation that is impossible to fulfill:
$$(E_\gamma + mc^2)^2 = E^2_\gamma + m^2 c^4$$
Unless $E_\gamma = 0$ (no photon) or $m = 0$ (a charged particle with no mass, which cannot exist).

However, it is a physical fact that **a charged particle inside an atom can absorb a photon** because in that case, the linear momentum and energy of the electrons and the atomic nucleus can be compensated. I've tried to write down the equations explicitly, to see if they always had a solution. For the sake of simplicity, consider a hydrogen atom at rest and a photon falling on it along the X direction. For the photon we have that $ (E, p_x, p_y ) = (E_0, E_0/c, 0) $, where $E_0 = h\nu$ or anything else convenient could be taken, for the electron + proton system, assuming that the photon has been completely absorbed, we could think that the atom experiences a recoil in the X direction with velocity V and therefore would eventually have:

$$\begin{bmatrix} E_0 + E_a \\ \cfrac{E_0}{c} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cfrac{m_1}{\sqrt{1-(v_1^2+V^2)}} + \cfrac{m_2}{\sqrt{1-(v_2^2+V^2)}} \\ \cfrac{m_1 V}{\sqrt{1-(v_1^2+V^2)}} +  \cfrac{m_2 V}{\sqrt{1-(v_2^2+V^2)}} \\ \cfrac{m_1 v_1}{\sqrt{1-(v_1^2+V^2)}} - \cfrac{m_2 v_2}{\sqrt{1-(v_2^2+V^2)}} \end{bmatrix}$$

where $E_a$ are the total initial energy of the atom because the relative motion of the electron and proton, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the transversal velocites of the electron and proton (we used units in which $c = 1$)

I have found that the previous system of three equations and three unknowns $(V, v_1, v_2)$ always has a solution with $V = cE_0/(E_0+E_a)$, so it would confirm that complete absorption of the photon is now possible. However, I have a doubt, I have assumed that the velocities perpendicular to the direction of impact of the electron and the proton are different and at the same time *and here is my criticism of the system of equations* I have assumed that in the direction of impact electron and proton acquire the same velocity (this hypothesis was unnecessary, but then we arrived at a system with more unknowns,  So there could still be a solution, but it wasn't easy to see if there would always be a solution.)

**My question is**: despite the fact that the above relativistic calculus is not an adequate description of a hydrogen atom (since it ignores quantum effects), is there a way to state the equations totally generally, assuming only the absorption of the photon, so that it can be seen that there is always a solution?

Answer (score 4):

quantum mechanics doesn't change anything. If you work in the hydrogen atom rest frame, the initial states are ($\hbar=c=1$):

$$ p^{\mu}_H = (M, 0, 0, 0) $$
$$ p^{\mu}_{\gamma} = (\omega, 0, 0, \omega)$$

for an initial state 4-momentum:

$$ p^{\mu} = (M +\omega, 0, 0, \omega) $$

(Note: when including all 3 spatial dimensions, it is traditional to make the $z$-axis the longitudinal axis)

The final state is just an excited hydrogen atom:

$$ p'^{\mu} = (M^*, 0, 0, \omega) $$

The energy component says:

$$M^* - M = \omega $$

which means the excited hydrogen atom less bound than the ground state by the energy of the absorbed photon.

3-momentum conservation just says the final state atom acquires a recoil velocity in the direction of the initial photon:

$$ v = \frac{\gamma M v}{\gamma M} = \frac p E = \frac{\hbar\omega/c}{Mc^2 + \hbar\omega} $$

Edit: Upon further review. The above answer is a common approximation. In the Breit-frame, there is no energy transfer, and $M^*-M$ is the photon energy; however, the rest frame is not the Breit frame...is on is approximately. But it's a very common approximation irl, since $\hbar\omega$ is on the order of eV, while $Mc^2$ is GeV.

So really, you need to assign the final state atom a 4-momentum:

$$ p'_{\mu} = (E', p'_x, p'_y, p _z) $$

(to be fully general). 3-momentum conservation gives:

$$ p'_x=p'_y=0$$
$$p'_z=\omega $$

so that:

$$ E' = \sqrt{(M^*)^2 + \omega^2} = (M+\omega) $$

That's 2 steps to get:

$$ M^* = M\sqrt{1+\frac{2\omega}M}\approx M\Big(1+\frac{\omega}M+\frac 1 4 \big(\frac{\omega}M\big)^2\Big)$$

which reproduces the original post's conclusion at 1st order.

Note, it's not $M^*$ that's being affected the photon energy isn't small compared with the target mass, it's just that the approximation "ignore recoil" fails.

And an nod to the original point: "A free particle can't absorb a photon", which iirc (I didn't really read the question), had a separate line of reasoning to show that.

Here you just say, for a particle:

$$ M^* = M $$

(e.g., you can't excite the electron--now you can a proton, but then it becomes a $\Delta^+$, aka photo production of pions)...

anyway:

That only works if $\omega=0$, which means scattering nothing to make nothing, which is equivalent to "forbidden" for all intents and purposes.

Comment: I only see one issue: the hydrogen atom's rest frame before the collision is a system, and the rest frame after the collision is another that moves at a constant speed relative to the first. As a result, I don't believe we can have the same initial and final whole because they occur in two different frames.

Comment: @Davius I see a problem too, gonna fix it. The final state $M^*$ is in the rest frame...I've done this so many times irl, I forgot we're not ignoring the tiny recoil momentum here, which is standard...esp in Raman scattering